# AES encrypted and decrypted values differ

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes, hmacsha1

In an Android app, I am trying to consume a WebAPI with an encrypted value in the JSON. I have a C# script which handles the encryption and I have adapted it to Android. The encryption method in short is adding a byte array a few variables, randomly generated IV, randomly generated salt and hmacsalt, adding the ciphertext which is generated from a Json String using AES/CBC/Pkcs7Padding and generating hmac and also adding that to the byte array. Converting this byte array to base64 gives me the encrypted string. I think everything works fine in this process since the WebAPI is able to decrypt my string. What the problem is the string is decrypted mostly correct but there is a date field and the date appears to be completely wrong.

I've been trying to adapt the C# to Android and what I am not sure about is how to specify the key length.
The key generators in both C# and Android are as follows.

```
var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, pbkdf2_iterations).GetBytes(pbkdf2_keyLength);
```

Here the pbkdf2_iterations = 100 and pbkdf2_keyLength =32;

```
SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
KeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 100, 32);
byte[] key = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec).getEncoded();
```

Here when initiating the PBEKeySpec, when I pass 32 for the key length, the byte[]key becomes 4 bytes and there is an exception saying unsupported key size 4 bytes but the WebAPI is able to decrypt my string with the date error. When I pass 256 for the key length, to make the byte[] 32 bytes, the WebAPI is not able to decrypt the string.

I am quite confused about what is the right way to do this.

To give an example about the faulty decrypted string, my plaintext to be encrypted is;

```
{"Username":"username","Password":"password","DateCreated":"2019-10-25T14:46:01.441Z"}
```

but the decrypted string is;

```
{"Username":"username","Password":"password","DateCreated":"2019-03-04T09:29:54.3516562Z"}
```

In this case, I suppose the encryption is correct but have no clue how the date value and format changes.

Any opinions about what may be wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

JSonObject Creation code

The Json data is created statically.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        String dateString = formatter.format(new java.util.Date());
JsonObject o = new JsonObject();
        o.addProperty("Username", "username");
        o.addProperty("Password","password");
        o.addProperty("DateCreated", dateString);
        String jsonString = o.toString();
```

And jsonString is passed for the encryption. I can see that its value is just the way I want.

Comment: This not a question on en-/decryption but on data serialization. You should replace the posted code parts with the data object and serialization code.

Comment: The C# API uses a key size in bytes and Java uses the key size in bits. So you can use 32 for the one and 256 for the other. As Robert said, if your string is different then it is because of the way the data is serialized / deserialized. If the key would be incorrect the result would either fail or it would not be printable text.

Comment: Hello guys thanks for the information. The Json data is created statically. I've edited the post with the JsonObject creation code. Can you see what might the problem be?